# Effect of file creation/opening on st_mtime and st_atime

Tags: unix, file-io

When I create or open a file in UNIX using `O_CREAT` flag, `st_mtime`,`st_ctime` and `st_atime` of the file changes. But when I create or open a file using `O_TRUNC` flag, only the `st_mtime` and `st_ctime` changes and not the `st_atime`.

From my understanding, `st_atime` changes when the file is accessed. When we open or create a file using O_TRUNC flag, are we not accessing the file?

Comment: AFAIK, Just opening a file (with whatever flags) does not change the times, atleast on linux. Can you give a code sample where this is happening?

Answer (score 6):

This question is a bit old, but an answer for future generations at least...

From stat(2) man page (on a host with a linux 2.6.32 kernel):

> The field st_atime is changed by file accesses,  for  example,  by  execve(2),  mknod(2),  pipe(2),
>   utime(2)  and  read(2)  (of  more  than  zero bytes).  Other routines, like mmap(2), may or may not
>   update st_atime.
>
> The field st_mtime is changed  by  file  modifications,  for  example,  by  mknod(2),  truncate(2),
>   utime(2)  and  write(2) (of more than zero bytes).  Moreover, st_mtime of a directory is changed by
>   the creation or deletion of files in that directory.  The st_mtime field is not changed for changes
>   in owner, group, hard link count, or mode.
>
> The  field st_ctime is changed by writing or by setting inode information (i.e., owner, group, link
>   count, mode, etc.).